# How to init a default class cluster subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class that I want to clusterize

CCluster (the public face)

the hidden workers who are subclassing CCluster
CInternalMutable : CCluster
CInternalFoo : CCluster

so I want the CCluster default init to return CInternalMutable
but in CInternalMutable I want to call [super init] but then we have a loop...

almost same problem with CInternalFoo which will init CInternalMutable then discard it

So how do I init my CInternalMutable class ?

For now I'm just not calling [super init] since CCluster is an 'abstract' class which inherit from NSObject

Answer (score 0):

Frankly what you are doing is just bad programming practices. Abstract classes should not have instances of them made so you should not really have a default init method that returns a subclass of it. However if you really want to do it you have two choices. The one I prefer would be to create another init function that is defaultInit or soemthing like that for the abstract class, or alternatively you could just say something like if([self class] == [CCluster class]) to be able to tell whether or not the caller is of the correct class.